# HTML Tag security in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, tags

I am working with codeigniter,
I enter the following value in a text box

```
    '>"><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

And save it with, geting that value using $this->input->post();

When we try to show the string in a text box,the text will be closed and showing like,

```
 <input name="field_14" id="field_14" type="text" value="'&gt;">[removed]alert([removed])[removed]"  /&gt;
```

in my config file

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

How to overcome this situation?
Anyone know?

Comment: Turn off CodeIgniter's built in CSS filtering and implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

Check your POSTDATA as GET or POST (Depends what method is used in the form) in your controller or model. If you are recordering in database you can filter data with escape function:

```
$field_14 = $this->db->escape($field_14));
```

Anyway, full code should be checked...